# subcaption package changing algorithm2e caption position

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subcaption, algorithm2e

I have a project which makes use of the `subcaption` and `algorithm2e` packages. For whatever reason, the subcaption package is causing the captions in the algorithms to be misplaced.

Here we have a MWE of the issue. Note that the `algorithm2e` package is defined with the [figure] option.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[figure,tworuled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
$f_1$ = Fase a calcular\;
\tcp{Início e fim do período considerado}
$t_1$ = Idade química do concreto na fase anterior à $f_1$\;
$t_2$ = Idade química do concreto na fase $f_1$\;
\caption{Cálculo das perdas por fluência do concreto para uma fase}
\label{fig:AlgFluencia}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Which results in the image below. Note that the caption is clearly not centered, with the text almost entirely flushed to the right.

[image]

If I then comment out the `\usepackage{subcaption}` line, I get the result below. The caption is nice and centered, no problems. (though there does seem to still be more space to the left than the right, though that might just be me. Regardless, its clearly better)

[image]

If the [figure] option in `algorithm2e` is removed, then there is no conflict between the packages, but I'd much rather keep it. The documentation on `algorithm2e` doesn't point to anything in regards to this (that I saw)... any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**
After seeing Werner's link to a solution, I thought all was solved, but thought too soon. Unfortunately, unlike the MWE shown, my project must in fact adopt an university-defined class file which makes use of [`atbeginend`](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/atbeginend.sty). With this package the same error occurs and is not corrected by the solution liked to be Werner. A more precise MWE (including Werner's solution) follows, along with the resulting image. It still makes use of the `book` class just to allow compilation by others, but the addition of `atbeginend` is sufficient to give the error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{atbeginend}
\usepackage[figure,tworuled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{%etoolbox
  \captionsetup{margin={-\algomargin,\algomargin}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
$f_1$ = Fase a calcular\;
\tcp{Início e fim do período considerado}
$t_1$ = Idade química do concreto na fase anterior à $f_1$\;
$t_2$ = Idade química do concreto na fase $f_1$\;
\caption{Cálculo das perdas por fluência do concreto para uma fase}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This can be replicated with only the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) as well. A solution is provided by [Adjusting the caption of an `algorithm2e` code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191122/5764). The difference in "overfull `\hbox`" measurement stem from the fact that you're using a `12pt` default font, while the linked duplicate uses `10pt`. The solution is to use `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{\captionsetup{margin={-\algomargin,\algomargin}}}`.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. In my actual project I actually already had `etoolbox`. Would this be considered a bug in the interaction of the packages or can it somehow be considered a "feature?" Also, while I understand its because the answer is the same as the one in the link, I gotta say... I hate that duplicate stamp.

Comment: There would definitely be a debate around whether a duplicate is considered a duplicate because of the question or the answer. It's probably a bad interaction between [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption). I think it may be something that should be fixed on `algorithm2e`'s side.

Comment: @Werner I'm fine with the duplicate tag, I get it. Just wish I hadn't gotten one. :( But I spoke too soon. The MWE uses the `book` class, but my project actually uses a university-defined class which makes use of [`atbeginend`](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/atbeginend.sty). With this package the same error occurs and is not corrected by the given solution. I've edited the OP showing the result.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments and the OP documented the answer by editing his question instead of self-answering.

Comment: @BambOo thank you for posting this. Indeed, this was one of my first questions on SE, hadn't learned the rules yet (and apparently forgot or rudely ignored PaulGessler's comment asking me to migrate my solution to an answer). I have fixed my mistake as best I can. I unfortunately can't expound further on the solution to improve the answer's body because I honestly don't remember the necessary details of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being to face the music and alter the university's class file, replacing `atbeginend` with `etoolbox`, which contains similar commands.

- `\AfterBegin{document}{-code-}` became `\AfterEndPreamble{-code-}`
- Any other `\AfterBegin{-env-}{-code-}` became `\AtBeginEnvironment{-env-}{-code-}`
- `\BeforeBegin{-env-}{-code-}` became `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{-env-}{-code-}`
- `\BeforeEnd{-env-}{-code-}` became `\AtEndEnvironment{-env-}{-code-}`

This along with [@Werner's solution in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201558/subcaption-package-changing-algorithm2e-caption-position?noredirect=1#comment469452_201558) solved the issue.

---

<sub>Thank you to [@BambOo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201558/subcaption-package-changing-algorithm2e-caption-position?noredirect=1#comment1382796_201558) for reminding me to write this as an answer, this question was from my starting days on SE.</sub>