# algorithm2e left-aligning the caption as the caption for figures in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, captions, algorithm2e

I am trying to left-align the caption of algorithms of algorithm2e to match the captions of the figures.

Taking a look at [Align Caption to the left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275131/align-caption-to-the-left) , here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[boxed,vlined,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{:}
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\normalfont}
\SetAlCapSkip{\abovecaptionskip\relax}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}   
\begin{document}
\chapter{ }

\begin{figure}[h]

\caption{Here is a long caption for an algorithm.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.}

\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
Some algorithm step \;
\caption{Here is a long caption for an algorithm.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This results in 
[image]

One solution candidate was to use the *figure* parameter as explained in [Adjusting the caption of an algorithm2e code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191122/adjusting-the-caption-of-an-algorithm2e-code) by considering

```
\usepackage[figure,boxed,vlined,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
```

This results in:
[image]

However, I would like the algorithms to be boxed (like in the first figure without boxing the caption), numbered and indexed (create a list of algorithms) independently.

Does anybody have ideas?

Edit:

After trying John Kormylo's solution I got:

[image]

The text seems to exceed the margin in this case.

Comment: Algoritm2e implements its own \caption at the \@makecaption level.  It has to in order to move the caption outside the box. It also totally ignores the caption package.

Comment: ...and furthermore the `algorithm2e` package does not offer any appropriate (internal) interfaces usable by the `caption` package, so unfortunately the `caption` package could not be adapted to the `algorithm2e` package either. Adapting `caption` to `float` was a nightmare but adapting it to `algorithm2e` (which contains modified code from the `float` package) is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this will only work for boxed algorithms.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[boxed,vlined,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{:}
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\normalfont}
\SetAlgoCaptionLayout{raggedright}
\SetAlCapSkip{\abovecaptionskip}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@makecaption}[2]{% no singleline check
  \addtolength{\hsize}{\algomargin}%
  \parbox[t]{\hsize}{\algocf@captiontext{#1}{#2}}%
  \addtolength{\hsize}{-\algomargin}%
}%
\renewcommand{\algocf@makecaption@boxed}[2]{%
  \addtolength{\hsize}{\algomargin}% again???
  \global\sbox\algocf@capbox{\algocf@makecaption{#1}{#2}}%
  \addtolength{\hsize}{-\algomargin}%
 }%
\renewcommand{\algocf@caption@boxed}{\vskip\AlCapSkip
  \leavevmode\hskip-\leftskip\box\algocf@capbox\hskip-\rightskip}
\makeatother

\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}
\chapter{ }

\begin{figure}[h]

\caption{Here is a long caption for an algorithm.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.}

\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
Some algorithm step \;

\rule{\hsize}{1ex}

\caption{Here is a long caption for an algorithm.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
\rule{\hsize}{1ex}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Alternate code fragment:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@makecaption}[2]{% no singleline check
  \parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{\algocf@captiontext{#1}{#2}}%
}%
\renewcommand{\algocf@makecaption@boxed}[2]{%
  \global\sbox\algocf@capbox{\algocf@makecaption{#1}{#2}}%
 }%
\renewcommand{\algocf@caption@boxed}{\vskip\AlCapSkip
  \leavevmode\hskip-\leftskip\box\algocf@capbox\hskip-\rightskip}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Hey John, your solution worked, yet, the algorithm caption exceeds the margin. I added a pic to the question. What do you think might have caused this? Thanks

Comment: That is not what I get.  Try updating your packages.  If that doesn't work, try the alternate version.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your edits! Worked like a charm.